# Could not create database for connection named "ged" could not find driver

Tags: postgresql, symfony, pdo, doctrine

I'm trying to use postgresql with symfony2.3. I've installed symfony using composer. When I try to create a database using the following command line : **php app/console doctrine:database:create** I get this error :

```
    Could not create database for connection named "ged"
    could not find driver
```

Knowing that both php_pdo_pgsql and php_pgsql are checked in PHP extensions (Wamp)
Also, I've copied the libpq.dll from the php folder to the apache folder, in Wamp.. 
Like I've seen in some threads with the same problem I'm facing.. Unfortunately it didn't solve my problem :(
I've checked the php.ini file in both Apache and Php folders, and it's all fine.. **extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll** as well as  **extension=php_pgsql.dll** are uncommented..
I've restarted all wamp services, and ultimately my laptop, to restart apache..
But the problem persists till now and I can't seem to figure out the issue !
How can I work with postgresql using symfony? And why does the pgsql driver seem to be unknown??

Here's my **parameters.yml** file (***app/config/parameters.yml***) :

```
    # This file is auto-generated during the composer install
    parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_pgsql
    database_host: localhost
    database_port: null
    database_name: ged
    database_user: null
    database_password: null
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    locale: en
    secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

And here's my **config.yml** file, the part concerning doctrine :

```
    # Doctrine Configuration
    doctrine:
    dbal:
    driver:   pdo_pgsql
    host:     localhost
    port:     ~
    dbname:   ged
    user:     ~
    password: ~
    charset:  UTF8
    # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver, add the path in parameters.yml
    # e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
    # path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    auto_mapping: true
```

Thank you in advance !

## *EDIT*: phpinfo(), the part related to PDO / PGSQL :

```
    PDO :

    PDO support enabled
    PDO drivers     mysql, pgsql, sqlite

    pdo_pgsql :

    PDO Driver for PostgreSQL   enabled
    PostgreSQL(libpq) Version   9.2.2
    Module version  1.0.2
    Revision    $Id$ 

    pgsql :

    PostgreSQL Support  enabled
    PostgreSQL(libpq) Version   9.2.2
    PostgreSQL(libpq)   PostgreSQL 9.2.2, compiled by Visual C++ build 1700, 64-bit
    Multibyte character support     enabled
    SSL support     disabled
    Active Persistent Links     0
    Active Links    0

    Directive   Local Value Master Value
    pgsql.allow_persistent  On  On
    pgsql.auto_reset_persistent Off Off
    pgsql.ignore_notice Off Off
    pgsql.log_notice    Off Off
    pgsql.max_links Unlimited   Unlimited
    pgsql.max_persistent    Unlimited   Unlimited
```

Comment: Could you please post result of `phpinfo()` or `php -i`?

Comment: First thank you for ur response @Crozin .. Well what part of phpinfo() u'd like to know about? Because it's a loong page

Comment: Part related to PDO/Postgres.

Comment: If u r looking to know about whether pgsql is enabled, it is. This is what I got in phpinfo() concerning this part : PDO
PDO support enabled
PDO drivers  mysql, pgsql, sqlite 

And for pdo_pgsql, I have this :
pdo_pgsql
PDO Driver for PostgreSQL enabled
PostgreSQL(libpq) Version  9.2.2
Module version  1.0.2
Revision  $Id$

Comment: Are you sure PHP uses the same `php.ini` file for both, Apache and CLI environment? https://www.google.pl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=php%20find%20php.ini%20location

Comment: Here's what I've just ran : php --ini and I had this :  Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)

Comment: How can I be sure PHP uses the same file according to this result ?

Comment: `php -i` from console and `<?php phpinfo();` through Apache should return the same value under _Loaded Configuration File_ entry.

Comment: Thank you @Crozin ! Problem solved :) I was editing Apache's php.ini file and not the other one! Thanks again ! Have a nice day